# Given the graphic sequence of a simple graph, how to construct the adjacency matrix?

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose I have the graphic sequence (7,6,6,6,5,4,4,2), how do I get the adjacency matrix out of it?

Comment: Well ... you could try to draw the graph. That's probably the easiest thing to do.

Comment: In general, there is no "the" adjacency matrix for a given graphic sequence even if you impose the constraint that the graph must be simple. For a given degree sequence, in general, several different graphs, and hence several different adjacency matrices exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can construct one (there may be many) of the realizations of a graphic sequence using the Havel-Hakimi Theorem:

> **Theorem** ([Havel, Hakimi, reference on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_%28graph_theory%29))
>   Let $s = s_{0}, \ldots , s_{d}, s_{d+1}, \ldots, s_{n}$ be a non-increasing sequence of non-negative integers with $s_{0} = d$. The sequence $s$ is graphic if and only if the sequence $s' = s_{1}-1, s_{2}-1,\ldots,s_{d}-1,s_{d-1}\ldots,s_{n}$ is graphic.

What this amounts to algorithmically is that we can take such a sequence and construct a graph (and hence the adjacency matrix, if that's the way you want to do it) by starting with a an empty graph on $n$ vertices (i.e. with no edges), labelled with the degree requirements (so vertex $i$ has initial requirement $s_{i}$), the repeatedly take the vertex with the largest remaining degree requirement $s_{j}$ adding making it adjacent to the $s_{j}$ vertices with the next highest remaining degree requirements.

In terms of the adjacency matrix, we start with a disconnected graph - all entries in the matrix are zero - then fill them in according to the scheme above.

Answer (score 0):

The graph has $8$ vertices, and $\tfrac{1}{2}(7+6+6+6+5+4+4+2)=20$ edges by the [Handshaking Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma).  We can exhaustively generate the non-isomorphic $8$-vertex $20$-edge graphs with vertex degrees between $2$ and $7$ using `geng` which comes with [nauty](http://cs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/nauty/) using:

```
geng 8 20:20 -d2 -D7
```

I wrote a script that filters out the ones that don't have degree sequence (7,6,6,6,5,4,4,2) leaving two remaining.  The two graphs are as follows:

[image: Two graphs with desired degree sequence]

I've marked the vertices with their degrees, and their corresponding adjacency matrices are given below.

$\begin{array}{|cccccccc|} \hline 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 
1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ \hline \end{array}
 \quad\quad\quad
\begin{array}{|cccccccc|} \hline 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 
1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ \hline \end{array}$